# A second person at a company contacted me about my application after I already had my first interview there. How do I respond?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

Last week I interviewed with a company. The interview went well, and right now I'm working on a test to show the company my skills. Today I received an e-mail from someone else in the company saying only the following:

> Thank you very much for your interest. Your profile sound very interesting and I would like to talk to you. Are you free to speak today or tomorrow?

The way it's worded I'm unsure if he's aware that I've already interviewed with the company. Or is this an invitation to a second interview even though I haven't finished their test yet? How should I respond?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should definitely respond if you're uncertain whether or not this is in relation to a second interview (from the content I doubt this but it's better to be safe than sorry).

You could then go on to ask whether the opportunity this person is referring to is different from the one you are currently in the interviewing process for - it could well be that someone from two different teams likes the look of your profile and want to interview you.

This gives the person who emailed you an update on your situation without assuming that they do or do not know about your current situation. They can respond with details on a new position, information about your second interview or an apology for bothering you again, which should cover all scenarios.